# find greatest last-modified files of /dirA/file, /dirB/file

Tags: bash

Suppose we have two directories, dirA, dirB, which the exact same PDF files, just different last modified.

What is a bash script (no awk) that can search through each file name (assume always in both dirA, dirB) and for each filename, outputs which of the files (dirA/file or dirB/file) has the greater  last-modified; file-modified-last? 
e.g.

```
if dirA/file.lastmodified > dirB/file.lastmodified 
##take action
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU stat:

```
shopt -s dotglob

for file in dirA/*; do
    [[ -f "dirB/${file##*/}" ]] || continue
    if (( "$(stat -c %Y "$file")" > "$(stat -c %Y "dirB/${file##*/}")" )); then
        # take action
    fi
done
```

Comment: `zsh`, `ksh93` and `bash` have `[[ file1 -nt file2 ]]` to compare file modification time. You may also need to take into consideration what you want to do with symlinks

Comment: Beware that if the filesystem supports timestamps with a reosolution better than 1 second, this will fail, as `stat -c %Y` rounds the timestamp to an integer number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Bash, ksh, zsh and even ash have a `-nt` operator for the `[` builtin (and in bash/ksh/zsh the `[[ … ]]` construct) that tests whether a file is newer than another.

```
for x in dirA/*; do
  y=dirB/${x#*/}
  if [ "$x" -nt "$y" ]; then
    # The file in dirA is more recent
  elif [ "$y" -nt "$x" ]
    # The file in dirB is more recent
  else
    # The two files have the same modification time
    # or the file doesn't exist in dirB
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with GNU tools:

```
find dirA dirB -type f -printf '%T@/%p\0' |
  tr '\n\0\t/' '\0\n/\t' |
  sort -k3 -k1,1rg |
  uniq -f2 |
  cut -f2- |
  tr '\0/\t' '\n\t/'
```

Would report every file in both dirA and dirB (and their subdirectories) except that if a file is common to both, only the newest (or if they are the same age, any one of them at random).

That only works for values of `dirA` and `dirB` like `"dirA"`, that is that don't contain blank or slash characters, though there's no restrictions on the paths of the files they may contain.

With `-type f`, only regular files are reported (not symlinks, fifos, devices...).

`find`'s `-printf`, the `g` sort type, `uniq`'s `-f` options and the ability of `sort`, `uniq` and `cut` to cope with NUL characters are GNU specific.